# Вывод всех пользователей с $_SESSION['username'];

Tags: php

Когда мы делаем вот так:

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['username'];

?>
```

У нас выводит наше имя, которое в сессии.
А как вывести все имена, которые в сессии? 
И можно ли вообще укоротить время сессии?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный путь - написать свой [Session Handler](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) который будет хранить все в какой-нибудь БД (например SQL). Тогда тебе можно будет делать запросы ко всем сессиям хоть по `username` хоть по чему угодно

Answer (score 0):

1) Если я правильно понял вопрос, при каждом действии пользователя пишите дату последнего действия в БД. А при выводе вам надо будет только найти пользователей с действием за последние 5 (10, 15, ...) минут.
 2) В настройках php укажите:

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime _секунды_
php_value session.cookie_lifetime _секунды_
```

Или в скрипте:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', _секунды_);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', _секунды_);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
print_r($_SESSION);
var_dump($_SESSION);
foreach($_SESSION as $value){echo $value;}
```

По моему файлы сессии убиваются каким-то скриптом на linux в папке /tmp

Comment: Ему немного другое надо) Что-то типа 

    foreach ($allSessionsOnServer as $UID => $_SESSION)
      echo $UID.': '.$_SESSION['username'].'<br />';

=)

Comment: Вот это уровень чтения мыслей. Тут пахнет либо мистикой, либо коллективной разработкой))

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $val) echo $key . "=" . $val . "<br>";
```

ну или можно попробовать вообще так

```
echo implode(',',$_SESSION);
```

Comment: Кто вам сказал, что в `$_SESSION` хранятся все пользователи? В данном массиве хранится пользователь, который обращается к серверу, данный массив работает от пользователя - который обращается к серверу.никогда данный массив не доступен всем, он работает уникально каждому - другим не виден. Кроме как перебрать сессионные файлы, никак не получить.